# Getting counts of row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

There's a table variable (I'll write it as a regular table here)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (memberid int, producttype varchar(7))
```

This table has hundreds of thousands of rows, but for this example I've added a lot less

```
Insert into test values(1,'book')
Insert into test values(1,'clothes')
Insert into test values(2,'book')
Insert into test values(3,'book')
Insert into test values(4,'clothes')
Insert into test values(5,'book')
Insert into test values(5,'clothes')
Insert into test values(6,'book')
Insert into test values(7,'book')
```

I need to get:

- the memberids that have 'book' only
- the memberids that have 'clothes' only
- the memberids that have both 'book' & 'clothes'

e.g.

```
Member     Book      Clothes      Both
  1          0          0           1
  2          1          0           0
  3          1          0           0
  4          0          1           0
  5          0          0           1
  6          1          0           0 
  7          1          0           0
```

I had managed to get it to work with sub-queries, but because of the size of the table it could take over 2 minutes to run.

I would appreciate if anyone knows a better way to achieve this?

Comment: So what have you tried, why didn't it work? You ask  "what is a better way", but a better way that *what*? If you used subqueries, show us those subqueries. You haven't shown us anything that our attempts can be "better" than.

Comment: As a rule, the place to start optimization is the _execution plan_. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    memberid,
    case when max(producttype) = 'book' then 1 else 0 end book,
    case when min(producttype) = 'clothes' then 1 else 0 end clothes,
    case when min(producttype) <> max(producttype) then 1 else 0 end both
from test
group by memberid
```

This works because there are only two possible `producttype`s. If you actually have more, then you need some expressions that are more complicated (and possibly more efficient), such as:

```
case when count(*) = sum(case when producttype = 'book' then 1 end)
    then 1
    else 0
end book
```

Comment: @Ragnar: are you running the very last version of the query? I edited my answer few minutes ago.

Comment: That looks great,  it will only be 2 variations and a both.  So this could be great.  I'll give it a try tomorrow on the full dataset & let you know.  But thanks for all your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @ragnar . . . This is a better solution than the alternatives.  No CTE or subquery is needed and `count(distinct)` is usually more expensive than other aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, I see your point. I'll mark this as the answer for anyone else who has the same problem.

Comment: If you only got two possible values the logic can be simplified to: `case when MAX(producttype) = 'book' 
        then 1 
        else 0
    end book,
    case when MIN(producttype) = 'clothes' 
        then 1 
        else 0
    end clothes,`

Comment: @dnoeth: ah yes, you are correct, that's shorter a query (although no performance benefit since both `min()` and `max()` need to be computed for each group). I changed the query accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CTE to get if each member has `book` and/or `clothes`:

```
with cte as (
  select memberid,
    count(distinct case when producttype = 'book' then 1 end) book_flag,
    count(distinct case when producttype = 'clothes' then 1 end) clothes_flag
  from test 
  group by memberid
)
select memberid,
  case when book_flag > clothes_flag then 1 else 0 end book,
  case when clothes_flag > book_flag then 1 else 0 end clothes,
  book_flag * clothes_flag both
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e5c2cb39dbc13012ef57d8b8ed8016d).
Results:

```
> memberid | book | clothes | both
> -------: | ---: | ------: | ---:
>        1 |    0 |       0 |    1
>        2 |    1 |       0 |    0
>        3 |    1 |       0 |    0
>        4 |    0 |       1 |    0
>        5 |    0 |       0 |    1
>        6 |    1 |       0 |    0
>        7 |    1 |       0 |    0
```

Comment: That's great thanks, I hadn't heard of cte before.  Time to brush up on my SQL skills :)

Comment: @Ragnar here is a link where you can find more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `MAX(case when producttype = 'book' then 1 else 0 end)` should be more efficient than `COUNT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @dnoeth sure. If there are really *hundreds of thousands of rows* in the table then this is an option worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

A table variable with hundreds of thousands of rows is going to be problematic for you.

If you check your query plan, you'll likely see that the optimizer expects that table variable to only contain one row.

Changing the structure to a local temp table, and perhaps adding an index to `producttype`, should significantly improve the performance of the query even before you optimize your code.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (memberid int, producttype varchar(7));

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX tempTest ON #TEST(producttype);
```